# Fido2 on Android, how to get the user handle (user id) back

Tags: android, kotlin, fido

I'm trying to use [Fido2](https://developers.google.com/identity/fido/android/native-apps) on Android. I've managed to create a credential with the following code:

```kotlin
val options = PublicKeyCredentialCreationOptions
    .Builder()
    .setRp(PublicKeyCredentialRpEntity(params.rpId, params.rpName, null))
    .setUser(
        PublicKeyCredentialUserEntity(
            Base64.decode(params.userId, Base64.URL_SAFE),
            params.userName,
            params.userName, // TODO ask declan about icon?
            params.userName
        )
    )
    .setChallenge(Base64.decode(params.challenge, Base64.URL_SAFE))
    .setParameters(
        listOf(
            PublicKeyCredentialParameters(
                PublicKeyCredentialType.PUBLIC_KEY.toString(),
                params.pubKeyAlg
            ),
        )
    )
    .build()

val fido2ApiClient = context.reactContext?.let { Fido.getFido2ApiClient(it) }
val task = fido2ApiClient?.getRegisterPendingIntent(options)

task?.addOnSuccessListener {
    try {

        context.currentActivity!!.startIntentSenderForResult(
            it.intentSender,
            REGISTER_REQUEST_CODE,
            null,
            0,
            0,
            0
        )

    } catch (e: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
        RNLog.w(context.reactContext as ReactContext ?, "ROPO ERROR $e")
    }

}

task?.addOnFailureListener {
    RNLog.w(context.reactContext as ReactContext?, "Failure to start intent $it")
}
```

And retrieval (signing) is done via:

```kotlin
val allowedKeys = ArrayList<PublicKeyCredentialDescriptor>()
for (i in 0 until params.allowCredentials.size) {
    val keyHandle: String = params.allowCredentials[i]
    val keyHandleByte = Base64.decode(keyHandle, Base64.URL_SAFE)
    allowedKeys.add(
        PublicKeyCredentialDescriptor(
            PublicKeyCredentialType.PUBLIC_KEY.toString(),
            keyHandleByte,
            null
        )
    )
}

val options = PublicKeyCredentialRequestOptions.Builder()
    .setChallenge(params.challenge.toByteArray())
    .setRpId(params.rpId)
    .setAllowList(allowedKeys)
    .build()

val fido2ApiClient = context.reactContext?.let { Fido.getFido2ApiClient(it) }
val task = fido2ApiClient?.getSignPendingIntent(options)

task?.addOnSuccessListener {
    try {

        context.currentActivity!!.startIntentSenderForResult(
            it.intentSender,
            SIGN_REQUEST_CODE,
            null,
            0,
            0,
            0
        )

    } catch (e: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
        RNLog.w(context.reactContext as ReactContext ?, "ROPO ERROR $e")
    }

}

task?.addOnFailureListener {
    RNLog.w(context.reactContext as ReactContext?, "Failure to start intent $it")
}
```

This calls both work with activity listeners. Here is the piece of code that handles the response of the signing/retrieval:

```kotlin
when (resultCode) {
    Activity.RESULT_CANCELED -> {
        retrievePromise!!.reject("authenticationCanceled", null, null)
    }

    Activity.RESULT_OK -> {
        if (!intent!!.hasExtra(Fido.FIDO2_KEY_CREDENTIAL_EXTRA)) {
            retrievePromise!!.reject("authenticationError", null, null)
        } else {
            val credential = PublicKeyCredential.deserializeFromBytes(intent.getByteArrayExtra(Fido.FIDO2_KEY_CREDENTIAL_EXTRA)!!)
            val response = credential.response
            if(response is AuthenticatorErrorResponse) {
                retrievePromise!!.reject("authenticationError", response.errorMessage, null)
            } else {
                val userHandle = (response as AuthenticatorAssertionResponse).userHandle // THIS IS NULL!!!
                retrievePromise!!.resolve(Base64.encodeToString(userHandle, Base64.URL_SAFE))
            }

        }
    }
}
```

However the problem is when I try to access the `AuthenticatorAssertionResponse.userHandle` the value is not there, it is null.

[image]

> Decompiled class, zze property should contain the bytes for the user handle

[This response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70773179/publickeycredentials-webauthn-internal-authentication-missing-userhandle-on-an) seems to suggest on Android it is not possible to get access to the user handle.

I'm really wondering if I'm doing something wrong here.

As additional data point [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#sctn-authenticator-credential-properties-extension) clearly states an extension can be added to indicate in-device saving of the key, which should then store/return the user handle property. However, I cannot seem to find a way to add this extension on the Kotlin code:

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work. As is turns out you need to specify the resident key in the as an Authenticator Selection when building the PublicKeyCredential:

```kotlin
.setAuthenticatorSelection(
    AuthenticatorSelectionCriteria
        .Builder()
        .setAttachment(Attachment.CROSS_PLATFORM)
        .setRequireResidentKey(true)
        .build()
)
```

Then Android will only show the possible authentication methods that support resident keys (NFC/USB) and the user handle will be populated.